# create side by side bar chart with different measures

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data looks like that

[image]

i would like to create a side by side bar chart (will be three bars per each month) one bar to shows the count of orders created during month, the other will be the count of orders dispatched during this month and the third will be count of orders received during this month. the point is that I have to show the values based on the year that the user will choose from a filter.

i can do each measure as one chart but i tried to do it in one side by side bar but i couldn't ... can you please help me

here is the work book
https://community.tableau.com/thread/333776

Comment: Read about how to pivot data  in the Tableau online help. It will simplify your problem.

Answer (score 1):

See this thread [create side-by-side bar chart in Tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63948953/create-side-by-side-bar-chart-in-tableau/63988372#63988372)

Pivot three fields with dates and it will solve your problem

[image: Desired Viz]