# create side-by-side bar chart in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, visualization

I have 2 dimensions, “departure” & “arrival”. Both these dimensions are in DATETIME format.
I want to display the number of records having departure & arrival for each hour (0 to 23hrs), as side-by-side bar chart.

I have tried different ways to create the visualization, but I can't figure out where I am going wrong.
I have attached my Tableau file.

Sheet: Wrong_count_for_arrival --> If i choose, "Departure" in my Column field, The "departure" count is correct, however, "Arrival" count is wrong.
And, if i choose, "Arrival" in my Column field, The "Arrival" count is correct, however, "Departure" count is wrong.

Sheet: double_values --> To correct above, if i put the "Departure" & "Arrival" in Columns field, then I am getting double values for both "departure" & "arrival" count.

I am trying to get visualization similar to "Wrong_count_for_arrival", but with correct count.

Attached is the Tableau workbook. [Tableau workbook-sample data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1buL5vqDD1dMC30gAhAcNFZT5IfLhGNpe/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your requirement arrival and departures are not related.
I achieved your desired view by doing these simple steps-

1. Pivot the two fields in data tab of tableau itself
2. let's say first field after pivot be 'arr or dep' which will be a dimension and another field be 'time' which will be date field.
3. add calculated field using datepart('hour', [time]) then create bins of size = 1 from this field
4. You'll get your desired view by adding hour_bins and 'arr or dep' to columns, sum(number of records) to rows and additionally arr_or_dep to color marks

[Image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9xYA.png)

Comment: Still if your times are related and you want to keep them related, add one row-id column before pivoting two fileds

Comment: Thank u so much Anil. It is exactly as I wanted.